# Why cannot use class A in generic class of A

Tags: java, object-oriented

I noticed something strange when I tried to use public method of A class in generic class B of A but it seems I can't. Is it relate to restrictions on generics. I mean Cannot Create Instances of Type Parameters rule.

```
public class A{
    public void a(){System.out.println("Hello!");}
}

public class B<A>{
    public void b(A arg){arg.a();}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
public class B<A>{
```

You are making `A` the **name** of the generic parameter. This means that inside `B`, `A` no longer refers to your class `A` - it can refer to any class!

For example:

```
public class A{
    public void a(){System.out.println("Hello!");}
}

public class B<A>{
    public void b(A arg){/*arg.a();*/}
}

public class C{
}

// inside some function:
B<C> b = new B<C>();
C c = new C();
b.b(c);
```

I run `b.b(c);` even though `c` is not your class `A`, because inside `B<C>.b` it's a different `A` - the generic parameter - which is actually `C` because we are using `B` with `C` as parameter.

(actually, it's just `Object` with some compiler magic, but [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is beyond the scope of this question)